# Getting error in Python 2.7 "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. "

Tags: python, python-2.7, tomcat, cgi

I am new to this and using Apache Tomcat server and a Python 2.7 CGI script.

For testing purpose I am doing some coding but I am getting the following error:

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
> The document will render with garbled text in some browser
> configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
> US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
> declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
> mark as an encoding signature

#### webs.py

```
import cgi, cgitb   
# Create instance of FieldStorage  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()   
# Get data from fields 
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name') 
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')  
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"
print "<html>" 
print "<head>"
# print "<meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>"
# print "<meta content='utf-8' http-equiv='encoding'> "
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>" 
print "</head>" 
print "<body>" 
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name) "
print "</body>" 
print "</html>"
```

My HTML form:

```html
<form action="/cgi-bin/webs.py" method="post"> 
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />  
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Plz don't use a 15 year old technlogy like CGI. Look into a real Python webserver: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: I want to use python for odoo modification then which things should i use??

Comment: Please remove that image and paste your error message into the question as _text_ (in a code block to preserve formatting).

Comment: IMHO, using old-fashioned CGI is ok for simple stuff, but it gets unwieldy for larger projects.

Comment: Errro msg is "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature"

Comment: I just noticed that you have `print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name) "`. There shouldn't be that final `"`.

Comment: @PM2Ring What should i do to complete this?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for response give me answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You should put a proper `meta http-equiv="Content-Type"` into your HTML documents (both the page that contains your form and the HTML generated by your CGI script). Eg

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You appear to have a pair of such `<meta>` tags in your script, but they're both commented out...

Note that if you declare that the `charset` is UTF-8 then you should make sure that the docs actually *are* encoded as UTF-8. If they only contain plain ASCII-safe chars you don't need to do anything, since the UTF-8 versions of those chars are identical to their ASCII codes.

BTW, if you've set up your paths in Apache properly you shouldn't need `/cgi-bin` in your form `action` attribute.

---

I've just tested your Python CGI script and a proper HTML file containing your form.

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>CGI test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="cgi-bin/qwebs.py" method="post"> 
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br>  
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### cgi-bin/qwebs.py

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cgi, cgitb  

# Create instance of FieldStorage  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields 
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name') 
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>" 
print "<head>"
print "<meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>"

print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>" 
print "</head>" 
print "<body>" 
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>" 
print "</html>"
```

I used Python's simple Web server:

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer
```

which by default serves on port 8000, and I put the CGI script in a `cgi-bin` folder in the current directory.

Everything worked as it should. So I suspect that you need to fix your Apache configuration. Make sure your CGI path is correct and that you have enabled `.py` files to be called as CGI.

Comment: Where did you put index.html?

Comment: How can i start my port 8989??

Comment: @AshishAsodiya: To keep things simple I put that index.html file in the current directory, which is my main Python scripts directory, and I also ran `python -m CGIHTTPServer` in that directory, so it automatically started up serving that index.html file.